# jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 POST 500 (Internal Server Error) with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I am using ajax to call another php page

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/coffee_note/ajax/coffeeN_list.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#shop').html(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

But it shows an error in the console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/coffee_note/ajax/coffeeN_list.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
m.ajaxTransport.a.send @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
refreshList @ coffeeN.js:20
(anonymous function) @ coffeeN.js:93
m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4

coffeeN.js:28 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

I am not sure if my code is wrong or not, but I do not find any bug so far.

Here is mysql error report:

```
{
    "pma_version": "4.4.10",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "45.0.2454.85",
    "user_os": "Mac",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.27",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "en",
    "configuration_storage": "disabled",
    "php_version": "5.5.27",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 235,
                "func": "",
                "context": [
                    "                lastException = null;",
                    "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                    "            }",
                    "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                    "",
                    "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                    "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                    "    return report;"
                ],
                "column": "",
                "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "getFieldValidators",
                "line": 302,
                "column": "40",
                "context": [
                    " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                    " */",
                    "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                    "{",
                    "    // look for field bound validator",
                    "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                    "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                    "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // look for registered validators"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "validate_field",
                "line": 418,
                "column": "21",
                "context": [
                    "{",
                    "    var args, result;",
                    "    var $field = $(field);",
                    "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                    "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                    "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                    "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                    "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                    "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                    "        } else {",
                    "            args = [];"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 511,
                "column": "13",
                "context": [
                    "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                    "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                    "        // run all field validators",
                    "        var errors = {};",
                    "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                    "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                    "        }",
                    "        // run all fieldset validators",
                    "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                    "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                    "        });"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
                "line": 279,
                "column": "33",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.m.event.dispatch",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "8436",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "19",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "5139",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Object.m.event.trigger",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "7537",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15404",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Function.m.extend.each",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "2973",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "index.php?target=sql.php"
    },
    "script_name": "index.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "current_index": "0"
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this situation? Thank you.

Comment: I know you're receiving a console error but what does your network tab say? You have an internal server error and the network tab will give you more detail about what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the error report in mysql? If so, I just update the report.

Comment: But it shows a lot of message, it may be a hard work to examine. Sorry.

Comment: Open your chrome developer tools then at the top left beside the 'Elements' tab click the 'Network' tab. Now try to make your ajax request and you will get an update that has the name, it will say POST etc, then it will go red. Click that link under name when it goes red and it will be able to provide you some feedback from your XHR error.

Comment: It shows somethings here, but I cannot find any clues here.

Comment: Do you mean the thing in headers or somewhere else?

Comment: try to set url like, `url: window.location.origin+'/coffee_note/ajax/coffeeN_list.php'`

Comment: A *500 Internal Server Error* happens on your **server** (where the PHP runs). Check the web server's error log

Comment: Thank you, I find the error in the error_log! Thanks a lot.